# Trouble in executing the SQL query using c#

Tags: c#, sql, execute

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace ConsoleCSharp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Class1.
    /// </summary>
    class DataReader_SQL
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add code to start application here
            //
            try
            {
                SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Network Library=dbmssocn;Data 

Source=sourcename,1655;database=Oracle;User id=sysadm;Password=password;");
                thisConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand thisCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
                thisCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SYSADM.PS_RQ_DEFECT_NOTE where ROW_ADDED_OPRID = 'github'";
                SqlDataReader thisReader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (thisReader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(thisCommand.CommandText);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                thisReader.Close();
                thisConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.Thanks. I want to execute SQL query using c# and get the results on console.I guess there is some problem with my code.Please review and let me know the inputs.

Comment: Well what exactly is wrong here? You mention you want to get the results on the console. Great. You've already got a `Console.WriteLine` so what do you think you need to do to write the results to the console too? Also, please look up parametrised SQL queries when you get a chance. Your SQL code is very insecure. Also wrap your SQL connections in `using`'s

Comment: @Arran Actually my code gets quits just after connection extablishment and my SQL query doesnt gets executed.

Comment: Run the query on the database yourself... `SELECT * FROM SYSADM.PS_RQ_DEFECT_NOTE where ROW_ADDED_OPRID = 'github'` ...does it return anything? Debug this. Put a breakpoint on `thisReader.Read()`...check what is inside it. Check if it any has rows. We cannot do this for you.

Comment: Yess it has data in the database.can you please review my code and comment if i am missing nything.

Comment: You have put a breakpoint inside inside the `while` loop yes? Does it get executed/does it enter the loop? You need to be debugging this, putting a breakpoint and debugging the application as it goes through each step.

Comment: Are you connecting to an Oracle server, or a Microsoft SQL Server server?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Oracle Server

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print the query data, you should run a command like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(thisReader["ROW_ADDED_OPRID"].ToString());
```

..inside the while loop.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually my code is not executing the SQL query and it quits just after connection establishment.

Comment: here are some some examples of sql querying: [akadia.com](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_data_reader.html) just see the sql part.. Check also the connection string, maybe it isn't correct: try this website, there are connections string for different database servers: [connectionstrings].(http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're trying to use the SQL Native Client (normally for use for connecting to Microsoft SQL Server) rather than using an Oracle client. Whilst the `System.Data.OracleClient` namespace does exist, [it is deprecated](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=144260). Instead, you may want to consider connecting using an `OleDbConnection` with the appropriate connection string, so something like:

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Network Library=dbmssocn;Data Source=sourcename,1655;database=Oracle;User id=sysadm;Password=password;")
{
    con.Open();
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand() )
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SYSADM.PS_RQ_DEFECT_NOTE where ROW_ADDED_OPRID = 'github'";

        using(IDataReader thisReader = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
        {
            while (thisReader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(thisReader["fieldname"]);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    };
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```